# $_SESSION doesn't start

Tags: php, session, cmd

When user is logged in nothing is displayed on the screen(Error-reporting is on).
It's like the `$_SESSION` is  not true?

```
<?php

 include_once('../includes/connection.php');


 if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
 ?>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>wa</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/stylesheet.css">
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

 <br />
 <ol>

 <li><a href="add.php">Add Article</a></li>
 <li><a href="delete.php">Delete Article</a></li>
 <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

</ol>       
</div>
</body>

</html>



<?php

 } else {

 if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = md5($_POST['password']);


 if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
 $error = 'All fields are required!';
 }else {

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password = 
         ?");

$query->bindValue(1, $username);
$query->bindValue(2, $password);

$query->execute();
$num = $query->rowCount();

 if ($num == 1) {
 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();

} else{

 $error = 'Incorrect details!';
}
}


}

  ?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Visuality dashboard</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

 <br /><br />

 <?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
 <small style="color:#aa0000;"><?php echo $error; ?>
 <br /><br />
<?php } ?>





<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="något">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="något">
<input type="submit" value="Login" />



</div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
 </html>

<?php
}






?>
```

Comment: session_start(); ? Eventually how you store the data inside $_SESSION ?

Comment: I think you just forgot "session_start();". just put this in your first line or somewhere on top of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call session_start(); at the beginning of your PHP file. If you have multiple files then adding it once to your connection file will work for all of them.

Read more on Sessions in PHP [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: @Tobias No problem. If this resolves your problem can you click the accepted answer button? :)

Answer (score 0):

At line 39 `md5$_POST['password']);` you missed "("

```
md5($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every php file which has $_SESSION variable needs to include session_start(); on the top of the page.

When page gets a white screen after loading, you should see php_error_log for possible syntax errors (could be missing ";").
Please, review your code.
Hope it helps you.